# What is the minimum version of Xcode I can use for submission to app store

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6, app-store, appstore-approval

I have an app on the appstore currently that is built using Xcode 6 with a deployment target of iOS 7. The recent release Xcode 6.3, however only works on OSX 10.10

Can I submit updates to the app store by building on an earlier version of Xcode (6.2 in my case) because I am unable to update OSX to 10.10? Does Apple release documentation about this when it releases a new Xcode version? The only thing I found was this

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1806/_index.html

which says that I should aim to build with the latest version of Xcode but does not mention if the app would be rejected/approved if built with a lower version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum Version of Xcode is **5.1.1** as stated in iTunesConnect when you want to upload a new binary of your app. This information does obviously include, that you can of course use Xcode 6.2 for AppStore submission.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can build using the lower version of the SDK within reason I believe. Some older compilers may be missing features that Apple will eventually require, but in the short term shipping with 6.2 won't really hurt much.

That said, Xcode 6.3 should include the iOS SDK. Make sure you got it from the App Store, which includes the full suite of stuff.